# ORACLE SQL: Multiple Grouping Layers and Intermediate Results

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

In ORACLE SQL (ORACLE 19c), I'm looking for a way to get the following table content

[image]

... similarly structured (grouped) as follows:

[image]

In first column data has to be grouped by:

1. DEPARTMENT
2. JOB_START_DATE, if JOB_START_DATE is between '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
3. JOB_DESCRIPTION(s)
4. NAME(s)

In the second column, a "1" represents when persons started their job in 2021

Finally, intermediate results about the SUM of the persons who have started within a DEPARTMENT (in 2021) should be output (bottom) for each DEPARTMENT group.

**Code snipped to generate the table data:**

```
 SELECT 'Zimmer, Hans'   AS NAME,
        '1978-10-01'     AS JOB_START_DATE,
        '2021-01-31'     AS JOB_END_DATE,
        'Movie Composer' AS JOB_DESCRIPTION,
        'Score'          AS DEPARTMENT
   FROM DUAL
   
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT 'Armstrong, Louis' AS NAME,
        '1988-06-01'       AS JOB_START_DATE,
        '2021-06-30'       AS JOB_END_DATE,
        'Jazz Musician'    AS JOB_DESCRIPTION,
        'Score'            AS DEPARTMENT
   FROM DUAL
   
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT 'Davis, Miles'  AS NAME,
        '2011-10-01'    AS JOB_START_DATE,
        '2021-03-31'    AS JOB_END_DATE,
        'Jazz Musician' AS JOB_DESCRIPTION,
        'Music'         AS DEPARTMENT
   FROM DUAL
   
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT 'Coltrane, John' AS NAME,
        '2015-08-01'     AS JOB_START_DATE,
        '2021-06-30'     AS JOB_END_DATE,
        'Jazz Musician'  AS JOB_DESCRIPTION,
        'Music'          AS DEPARTMENT
   FROM DUAL
   
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT 'Cobain, Kurt'  AS NAME,
        '2021-08-01'    AS JOB_START_DATE,
        '2022-07-31'    AS JOB_END_DATE,
        'Rock Musician' AS JOB_DESCRIPTION,
        'Music'         AS DEPARTMENT
   FROM DUAL
   
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT 'Keys, Alicia'  AS NAME,
        '2021-09-01'    AS JOB_START_DATE,
        '2022-08-31'    AS JOB_END_DATE,
        'Pop Musician'  AS JOB_DESCRIPTION,
        'Music'         AS DEPARTMENT
   FROM DUAL
   
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT 'Tarantino, Quentin' AS NAME,
        '2021-03-01'         AS JOB_START_DATE,
        '2021-08-31'         AS JOB_END_DATE,
        'Movie Director'     AS JOB_DESCRIPTION,
        'Film'               AS DEPARTMENT
   FROM DUAL
   
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT 'Pitt, Brad'  AS NAME,
        '1999-10-01'  AS JOB_START_DATE,
        '2021-01-26'  AS JOB_END_DATE,
        'Movie Actor' AS JOB_DESCRIPTION,
        'Film'        AS DEPARTMENT
   FROM DUAL
   
 UNION ALL
 
 SELECT 'Nolan, Christopher' AS NAME,
        '2020-05-01'         AS JOB_START_DATE,
        '2021-03-31'         AS JOB_END_DATE,
        'Movie Director'     AS JOB_DESCRIPTION,
        'Film'               AS DEPARTMENT
   FROM DUAL;
```

Is it possible in ORACLE SQL to get the table data structured / grouped as wanted?

If so, how can I achieve that?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no clue, what to do to get my desired output format. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want to use `CUBE` with conditional aggregation and then filter on the grouping sets:

```sql
SELECT name,
       job_description ,
       department,
       COUNT(CASE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM job_start_date) WHEN 2021 THEN 1 END)
         AS number_of_2021_jobs
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       CUBE(name, job_description, department)
HAVING GROUPING_ID(name, job_description, department) IN (0, 6)
ORDER BY
       department
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | NAME | JOB_DESCRIPTION | DEPARTMENT | NUMBER_OF_2021_JOBS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Nolan, Christopher | Movie Director | Film | 0 |
> | Pitt, Brad | Movie Actor | Film | 0 |
> | Tarantino, Quentin | Movie Director | Film | 1 |
> |  |  | Film | 1 |
> | Cobain, Kurt | Rock Musician | Music | 1 |
> | Coltrane, John | Jazz Musician | Music | 0 |
> | Davis, Miles | Jazz Musician | Music | 0 |
> | Keys, Alicia | Pop Musician | Music | 1 |
> |  |  | Music | 2 |
> | Armstrong, Louis | Jazz Musician | Score | 0 |
> | Zimmer, Hans | Movie Composer | Score | 0 |
> |  |  | Score | 0 |

*Note: If you want the values in the same column then concatenate the `name`, `job_description` and `department` columns and put new-line characters between them.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b04975209cac37584476376ac29612e1)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I want. How can column "JOB_START_DATE" be added? I really need to know when a person exactly has started his/her job. When I add JOB_START_DATE in SELECT, CUBE, and HAVING clause, I'm getting a strange ouput... What does "IN (0,6)" in HAVING clause mean?

Comment: @Peter Use `MAX`? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=13326bdeab37641849f2a64c1fbf1757)

Comment: `IN (0, 6)` determines which grouping sets you want from the `CUBE`. Remove the `HAVING` clause and you can see all the generated rows; you just wanted the rows with all values or only the department value and the `0`th grouping set corresponds to all values and `6` to just the departments.